# Upgrading the RAM in a Dell T3400

Tags: memory

I have a Dell Precision T3400 with Windows 7 x64. It has 4 RAM slots in 2 banks. Currently, slot 00 (bank 0, slot 0) and slot 10 (bank 1, slot 0) have 1 GB PC2-6400 Dell RAM each. (ServerFault won't let me post more than 1 hyperlink, but it's Dell SKU A1312860)

I would like to upgrade the RAM and I found some [GSKILL 2GB PC2-6400](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231122) RAM. Can I combine the Dell and the GSKILL RAM for a total of 6GB RAM? If yes, does it matter how it's arranged? i.e. Bank 0 is GSKILL and Bank 1 is DELL or mix them for 3GB in each bank?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: link to the Dell RAM details: http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=A1312860

Comment: So, after I ordered the new RAM, I discovered that the above link left out an important detail: it's ECC RAM. So, In the end I could not mix the RAM chips. Cautionary tale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use any DDR2 PC-6400 (800Mhz) memory to upgrade your RAM... GSKILL, DELL, APACER, ADATA, OCZ really doesn't matter. Buy kit of 2x2GB as on your link with GSKILL described and just insert them in free slots. That's all.
Cheers & GL!

Comment: So, slot 0 with the two 1 GB Dell modules and Slot 1 with the two 2 GB GSKILL modules will work? I noticed Dell does not give the timings for their RAM. Will it make a difference if they don't match?

Comment: it's not really important if you use 1 2 1 2 or 2 2 1 1.. it will work in both schemes. Better if you do on primary channel 2 rams with 2gb (2x2gb) the second one 2x1gb -> it will be from left to right on motherboard: 1gb 2gb 1gb 2gb.

Comment: just an example of dual channel: http://www.virtual-hideout.net/reviews/Kingston_KHX_1600_DDR3/main.jpg